# How to load a text file from a server into iPhone game with AS3 in Adobe AIR?

Tags: iphone, ios, server, file

Im creating an iPhone game with Adobe AIR, and I want to be able to load a simple text msg into an dynamic text box on the games front screen from my server (and then be able to update that text file on the server, so it updates automatically in the game after the game is on the app store) How would I go about acheiving that? is it as simple as using a getURL? are there any specifical issues with trying to do this on the iPhone via AIR that I should be aware of?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use an `URLLoader` as you would with a classic flash application.

Something like that:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("url to load");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, 
    function(event:Event)
    {
        _myTextField.text = URLLoader(event.target).data as String
    }
);
```

There's no restriction on iOS regarding loading external URLs (as long as you ain't loading and interpreting code), but you should check if your user has an internet connection before trying to load the URL and handle it. You might also want to cache the returned file.